# Facebook LIke update through Ajax - not simple issue

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags, scrape

I have created a video page that loads videos dynamically using a database while the files are stored on the server. A video is preloaded on the page and that data can be Liked and posted to Facebook with no issue. When a new thumbnail is clicked, I'd like the Facebook Like information to change to the new video content (title, url, and image).
I've looked for a solution and there are many similar ones but their simple solution of adding `FB.XFBML.parse();` isn't working for me.
I update my meta tags when the Ajax call comes back successfully using:

```
$("meta[property=og\\:title]").attr('content', videoTitle); 
$("meta[property=og\\:url]").attr('content', "www.mySiteURL.com/index.php?videoID="+videoID);
$("meta[property=og\\:image]").attr('content', "www.mySiteURL.com/images/video/"+videoImageName);
```

But when I run the parse code right after these are set, I see the button refresh but it sill has the same content.
I can see that the meta tags actually update using Firebug.  It's just that the FB button doesn't properly re-scrape the page info to send to FB. I have the namespace set in my html tag and I have the other og:metas set up as well, but these are the three that I need to be re-scraped.

I saw in one post that someone used something similar to `ajax.complete(function(){FB.XFBML.parse();});` directly on the main page, I don't remember the exact code, but the idea was the same, and it still didn't work.  I figured just running it within my ajax function, on success, would be sufficient.

Am I missing anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Edit:
I should add that each video has its own direct URL that is inserted into the og:url since they are all loaded through ajax. 
The Facebook Linter/Object Debugger shows me all of the correct data for each video when I use one of these unique URLs, it's just a scraping issue - at least, with my limited knowledge on this, that's what it seems to be to me.

Comment: Does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) pick up the tags when you put in the specific URL for that video? You're not creating the meta tags with Javascript, right? It sorta looks that way in the question, but you also say each video has its own URL - so that URL should be returning the meta tags to the crawler, and you'd be pointing the like button to that URL, and changing the Like button dynamically, not the meta tags on the page itself

Comment: Thank you Igy! I had understood that I just had to change the meta tags and completely overlooked updating the href in the Like button code. I now update that code and the parsing works perfectly. I do have my meta tags already in place and only change them through jQuery - not that that really matters now anyways.
If you post your comment as a solution I can accept it as the best solution.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have been changing the meta tags of the current page dynamically - this isn't necessary and would cause problems with Facebook's scrape (which you can verify using [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)) -

Maintain one static URL per object, serve the meta tags from that URL (you can redirect other browsers if you want) and on the dynamic page change the Like button itself to point at the URL for the object being displayed currently (i.e remove the like button, add a new fb:like tag and re-call `FB.XFBML.parse();`)

Answer (score 1):

> I should add that each video has its own direct URL that is inserted into the og:url since they are all loaded through ajax. The Facebook Linter/Object Debugger shows me all of the correct data for each video when I use one of these unique URLs, it's just a scraping issue - at least, with my limited knowledge on this, that's what it seems to be to me.

No, it’s not a scraping issue – because the scraper does not care for your JavaScript, and thus never sees the meta tags you update *client-side*. It makes an HTTP request to your server, so what you do in any kind of client that is currently displaying the page is absolutely irrelevant.

What you need to do, is update the target URL the like button is pointing to: Replace the existing like button with new like button code with a href attribute containing the current video page URL, run FB.XFBML.parse on it – and then it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should call `FB.XFBML.parse();` after you've updated the meta tags, which causes the FBML tags to be rendered again.

[More info on `FB.XFBML.parse();` here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)